# Adobe Director (dcr) depth (z-index) problem

Tags: z-index, adobe-director

Can *.dcr depth (z-index) can be controlled such that a flash or some other layers can appear on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But you have to disable "Direct to stage" for the flash sprite and all other sprites which have such an option. Otherwise these sprites will always appear on the top.
If you disable this option then the order of the channels is the z-index. And you can use the lingo-property locZ to change the order too.
Important: Disabling "Direct to stage" will cost you performance.

Answer (score -1):

In short, no. You could embed the flash within your dcr though.

Comment: This answer is really wrong - sorry. Details can be found in my answer.

Comment: I do not know if you could set a flash "direct to stage" back then. It is impressive that someone still cares about Director and Flash though.